# Setting and getting QComboBox values from QPushButton

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyside

I have 4 `QComboBox` and I want set current values with `QPushButton`.

For example, I have a combo box name `startBOX` and when I change the value, I want to set it with a QPushButton `SetButton` and get the value from it.

[image]

I am using Python 2.7 and PySide.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to set the ComboBox from the push button? If so use signals.

```
btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Set")

def change_value():
    startBox.setCurrentIndex(0) # The index for the item you want.

btn.clicked.connect(change_value)
```

If you wanted to set the button text when the ComboBox value is changed then use the code below.

```
def change_value(*args):
    btn.setText("Set " + startBox.currentText())

startBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(change_value)
```

There are several signals that you can use. Those signals when activated can call a function or method. http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QComboBox.html

Comment: Thanks, I did it another way but yours are better. I wanted the first one. However, in the index I wrote startBox.currentIndex() instead of 0 to get the current value of the current Index.

Comment: m.akbari I noticed you have like 15 questions, and have accepted zero answers so far. If you find an answer actually answers your question, the standard thing to do is to accept it (that is the best form of thank you at this site!). See this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers